# Creating a distinct list of custom type in C#

Tags: c#, .net, linq

I receive a List of en entity framework type and want to only return the distinct values from the List. I'm using the following approach, however it's not uniquifying the list. Any suggestions?

Param: `List<Flag> flags`

```
List<Flag> distinctFlags = flags.Distinct().ToList();
```

The values of Flag are as follows: ID, Flag, FlagValue. Could I use linq in this instance?

Thanks.

Comment: What are your input values and what do you expect as output?

Comment: Is this inside or outside a dbcontext? Show more code please.  And if you can, give an example of the data before and after the transformation.

Comment: Group them up and pick a winner. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/489258/linq-distinct-on-a-particular-property/491832#491832

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Assuming `Flag` is one of your entity models, you could use a `partial` `class` and override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`. This also assumes that you have an `Id` property on on your `Flag` `class` which uniquely identities it.

```
//this namespace MUST match the namespace of your entity model.
namespace Your.Entity.Model.Namespace
{
    public partial class Flag
    {
        public override bool Equals(object obj)
        {
            var item = obj as Flag;

            if (item == null)
            {
                return false;
            }

            return this.Id.Equals(item.Id);
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return this.Id.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

Usage would look like this

```
List<Flag> distinctFlags = allFlags.Distinct().ToList();
```

Comment: You should also implement `IEquatable<T>` on the type.

Comment: And probably override `==` and `!=`

Comment: You only need to implement `Equals` & `GetHashCode`. Just make absolutely sure that your hash code value never ever changes - the value MUST be IMMUTABLE.

Comment: @svick agreed, that's a good performance suggestion. When dealing with large collections where performance is a concern, you can save the `cast` that is done when `Object.Equals(Object)` is called and `IEquatable<T>.Equals(T)` could have been called instead.

Comment: @OskarKjellin, you mean `overload` and there are definitely arguments for and against overloading `==` and `!=` among the other comparison operators. I would say that it is something to consider as opposed to a given though.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `flags` is a list of reference type, and distinct does not work as you expect!
This because Distinct() work not on the value of the flag in the list, but on its memory references (that are all differents).

You have to write a comparer class that teach to Distinct how to compare equal flag. Suppose you have this flag class:

```
public class flag
{ 
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Code { get; set; }
}
```

you should create a comparer class like this:

```
class FlagComparer : IEqualityComparer<flag>
{
    // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
    public bool Equals(flag x, flag y)
    {

        //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
        return x.Code == y.Code && x.Name == y.Name;
    }
}
```

and the call your statement:

```
List distinctFlags = flags.Distinct(new FlagComparer ()).ToList();
```

In this way, Distinct method know exactly how to compare equals flag istance.

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, if you wanto to follow my suggestion, you should write the comparer base as follow:

```
class FlagComparer : IEqualityComparer<flag>
    {
        // Products are equal if their names and product numbers are equal.
        public bool Equals(flag x, flag y)
        {

            //Check whether the compared objects reference the same data.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

            //Check whether any of the compared objects is null.
            if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) || Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
                return false;

            //Check whether the products' properties are equal.
            return x.HostID == y.HostID && x.RuleID == y.RuleID && x.Flag == y.Flag && x.FlagValue == y.FlagValue;
        }
    }
```

Of course, every property must be a value type.

Take a look here to clarify yourself:

- [Value Type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx)
- [Reference type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/490f96s2.aspx)

Comment: This would work, but overriding `Equals()` and implementing `IEquatable<T>` is more common approach, because it means you don't have to specify the comparer every time.