# Linq, unable to list only distinct results

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

I have three tables, car_type, car_manufacturer and car_model. When the user click on the particular vehicle type they want to browse, I'd like to show them a list of available manufacturers. The problem is the list of manufacturers is not distinct or unique. So if my db has three models from Mazda, Mazda will show up on the list 3 times.  This is my controller:

```
    public ActionResult Browse(string click_string)     
    {
         var x = carDB.Models
                 .Include(b => b.Manufacturer)
                 .Include(a => a.VehicleType)
                 .Where(a => a.VehicleType.TypeName == click_string);
         return View(x.ToList());
}
```

How can I write this to remove redundant listings? This is all new to me, so go easy on me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to query for `Manufacturers`, not for `Vehicles`:

```
var x = carDB.Models.Where(a => a.VehicleType.TypeName == click_string)
                    .Select(a => a.Manufacturer)
                    .Distinct();
```

Comment: This makes sense to me, but I get an error: "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[CarStore.Models.Manufacturer]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[CarStore.Models.VehicleModel]'. I understand what the error is asking, so how do I return a type of enumerable to the View?

Comment: You have you change your `View` to accept `IEnumerable<Manufacturer>`.  There should be done at the top of your `View` file, however I'm not 100% sure about that because I don't have much experience with MVC.

Answer (score 1):

It usually works well to try and avoid Distinct altogether. You want manufacturers? Get manufacturers. And determine from there which ones you need: the ones that produce models that have `click_string` in their type name:

```
carDB.Manufacturers.Where(manufacturer => manufacturer.Models
                   .Any(model => model.VehicleType.TypeName == click_string))
```

You may want to include `Models` and/or `VehicleType`, that depends on what you want to show in the view.

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying, and I'll commit to this line on thinking

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use [.Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) to return the distinct elements.

```
var x = carDB.Models
        .Include(b => b.Manufacturer)
        .Include(a => a.VehicleType)
        .Where(a => a.VehicleType.TypeName == click_string)
        .Distinct();
```

Comment: This won't work. It actually pulls up no rows when I add Distinct(). I'm not sure why it pulls nothing...

Comment: It depends on what the previous LINQ query contains, as it needs to be something that can be compared in order to pull out distinct entries.  If you just need the names, put in .Select(x => x.WhateverYourNameFieldIsCalled) to get a single String and then put .Distinct on that.

Comment: public ActionResult Index()
        {var x = carDB.Types.ToList();
            return View(x);
        }

Comment: Hey Jason, sorry, but I'm obviously not inserting my code properly in the comments section. The only linq I have before is getting my Vehicle types to show up as a list: var x = carDB.Types.ToList(); return View(x);

Comment: Sorry - you misread what I meant by previous.  I meant the query you are tagging .Distinct onto.  It is (sort of) an IEnumerable<Something> at that point.  That `Something` needs to be comparable for .Distinct to work.

Comment: Like .Distinct(a => a.Manufacturer);?

Comment: No. .Distinct accepts a compare function.  If you want to make your class comparable, see [this question and answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601674/creating-a-distinct-list-of-custom-type-in-c-sharp).  Otherwise you can do like my previous comment and get a single string of manufacturer names and use .Distinct on that.

Answer (score 0):

First try doing a `.Distinct()` at the end of the query, if it does not work you might need to provide a custom comparer for the .Distinct()

Comment: Yes, I did try a Distinct() at the end, to no avail :(

Answer (score 0):

add distinct

```
var x = carDB.Models
        .Include(b => b.Manufacturer)
        .Include(a => a.VehicleType)
        .Where(a => a.VehicleType.TypeName == click_string)
        .Select(y => y)
        .Distinct();
```

The .Select() might be a bit verbose but without trying it in my visual studio i put it in there for saftey