# How to bind custom model class in mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am new in MVC. I am working on a project where i have created a model class and also context class which is working good if i view the record in normal view.
but if i try to get the data in group by "Series_Name" and bind it into same model class it gives error. here is my code

Here is Model class and DBContextClass

```cs
[Table("tblvideo")]
public class TVSerial
{
    [Key]
    public Int64 Video_ID { get; set; }
    public string Series_Name { get; set; }
    public string Season_No { get; set; }
    public string Episode_No { get; set; }
    public string Episode_Name { get; set; }
    public string Time_Duration { get; set; }
    public string File_Url_480p { get; set; }
    public string File_Url_720p { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public bool Is_Active { get; set; }
    public string Image_Url_Small { get; set; }
    public string Image_Url_Big { get; set; }   
} 

public class TvSerialContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<TVSerial> TvSerials { get; set; }
}
```

Here is controller class:

```
public class TvSerialController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult ListAllTvSerial()
    {
        try
        {
            TvSerialContext tvContext = new TvSerialContext();
            List<TVSerial> tv = tvContext.TvSerials.ToList();
            return View(tv);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Content(ex.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Above code works as expected, but if i am doing this :

```
public ActionResult ListAllSeason(string serial)
{
    try
    {
        TvSerialContext tvContext = new TvSerialContext();
        List<TVSerial> tv = tvContext.TvSerials.Where(tvs => tvs.Series_Name == serial).Distinct().ToList();
        return View(tv);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return Content(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

it return all rows , i just want single row from every series_name and custom field "Series_Name,Season_No,Image_Url_Big"
i don't know how to achieve this.
getting result :[image]

Expected result:-
[image]

Comment: What do you mean _it return all rows_? It will only return the rows where `Series_Name == serial`. And do you have a custom Comparer? (if not the `.Distinct()` clause wont do anything. Best guess is you want a `.GroupBy()` but its not clear from your question what you want the output to be.

Comment: yeah actually i want groupBy Series_Name and want only 3 fields but i don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: Create a view model with just the 3 properties you want and use a `.GroupBy()` to project the vales into your view model. But you called you method `ListAllSeason` suggesting you want to group by the season?

Comment: yes that's right when i'll pass the parameter  ex:- Series_Name ="Breaking Bad" it should return the All season_No like 1,2,3,4,5.                                          So as you said i need another model for 3 properties and then also need another DbContext too ?

Comment: No, just a view model that you project the 3 property values into. I suggest you edit your question to show a sample of the data you want to return so its clear what your wanting to do and how you want to group the data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by creating a view model and using a `.GroupBy()` clause

```
public class TVSerialVM
{
  public string SeriesName { get; set; }
  public string SeasonNo { get; set; }
  public string ImageUrl { get; set; } 
}
```

and the query to project into your view model

```
List<TVSerialVM> model = tvContext.TvSerials.Where(t => t.Series_Name == serial)
  .GroupBy(t => new { t.Series_Name, t.Season_No, t.Image_Url_Big })
  .Select(t => new TVSerialVM
  {
    SeriesName = t.Key.Series_Name,
    SeasonNo = t.Key.Season_No,
    ImageUrl = t.Key.Image_Url_Big
  }).ToList();
```

Side note: Your duplicating data in the database (the season number and the image url). You should consider moving the image urls to another table with a relationship to the season number.

Answer (score 1):

The reason you are getting multiple values even though you are using distinct is the Distinct method does not know what "equal" is for TVSerial.

You can use Distinct with IEqualityComparer.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: actually i want groupBy Series_Name and want only 3 fields but i don't know how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Distinct is not guaranteed to on custom objects it doesn't know what to compare. I have used this SO in the past to make my custom object work with Distinct.

[Creating a distinct list of custom type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601674/creating-a-distinct-list-of-custom-type-in-c-sharp)

Comment: actually i want .GroupBy Series_Name and want only 3 fields but i don't know how to achieve this.