# Get Key From Group By Result

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, group-by

I have a list of data on which I applied group by with multiple keys. I want to retrieve only one key per td but it shows me all keys in one td
how would I achieve that
here is m code

```
  var _data = new List<Group<object, ShipWiseCargoHandling>>();

        ViewBag.Print = Print;
        try
        {
            _output = _portSer.GetShipWiseCargoHandling();
             _data = (from q in _output
            group q by new { q.SHT_DESC ,q.S_NAME,q.pqa_reg_no} into g
            select new Group<object, ShipWiseCargoHandling> { Key=new {BerthName= g.Key.SHT_DESC,ShipName=g.Key.S_NAME,RegNo=g.Key.pqa_reg_no}, Values = g }).ToList();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Connectivity to server is not available, Please try it later! " + ex.Message;                
        }
        return View(_data);
```

And I use this model in view this way

```
  @foreach (var item in (List<Group<object, ShipWiseCargoHandling>>)Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => item.Key)</td>
            </tr>
            foreach (var subitem in item.Values)
        {}}
```

Comment: `item.Key.BerthName`

Comment: Stephen it shows me error

Comment: You will need to change `object` to a model containing your 3 keys (`BerthName` etc)

Comment: Can you show me a sample because key contains different data type

Comment: Not exactly the same, but [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602217/how-to-bind-custom-model-class-in-mvc/33603090#33603090) should help - in your case the view model will also include a `IEnumerable<ShipWiseCargoHandling>` property for the collection