# Procedure Compare 2 Tables and Update DISTINCT records

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I hope you can help me solve my predicament.

I know there are different ways to accomplish this, and I am open to your suggestions. I am learning everyday. But please remember I am still a newbie. :)

**I am trying to correct a procedure that does the following:**

1. It finds all distinct records that does not exist
2. By comparing the [THEOPTION].[NAME] field with the [ProjectMaster].[Finance_Project_Number] field
3. It updates the distinct records that does not exist

First off; when I do a DISTINCT select in SQL, I get this value: 6982.

But the line of code in my procedure that is supposed to replicate this result, returns a result that is a few 100 records shy of my total records in the DB: 15 995

**This is the line:**

```
var deltaList = stageContext.ProjectMasters.ToList().Where(u => !allProjectNames.Contains(u.Finance_Project_Number)).Distinct().ToList();
```

**Here is my SQL query:**

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Finance_Project_Number]
FROM [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster]
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                        FROM [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION]  
                        WHERE [InterfaceInfor].[dbo].[ProjectMaster].[Finance_Project_Number] = [IMS].[dbo].[THEOPTION].[NAME])
```

**Below is my complete C# procedure:**

```
public static void NewRecords()
{
    using (var stageContext = new StagingTableDataContext())
    {
        using (var destinationContext = new DestinationTableDataContext())
        {
            var allProjectNames = destinationContext.THEOPTIONs.Select(u => u.NAME).ToList(); //12 622
            var deltaList = stageContext.ProjectMasters.ToList().Where(u => !allProjectNames.Contains(u.Finance_Project_Number)).Distinct().ToList(); //15 300

            deltaList.ForEach(u => u.Processing_Result = 0);
            deltaList.ForEach(u => u.Processing_Result_Text = "UNIQUE");

        }
        stageContext.SubmitChanges();
    }
}
```

Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Finding and updating the records that don't exist is a difficult concept to grasp.  What does it mean?

Comment: @DanBracuk I am trying to find all records (by identifier) that does not exist in the THEOPTION table, but do exist in the ProjectMaster table. But only the DISTINCT records. As there are multiple record per identifier due to CRUD operations. Hope this makes sense!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your ProjectMaster entity does not override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, yet both are need for `Distinct()` to work correct.

Have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601674/creating-a-distinct-list-of-custom-type-in-c-sharp/9601805#9601805) which gives additional information on how to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in partial classes.

In your SQL query, you call distinct on *one single value*, in your LINQ query you call distinct on a *complete record* in ProjectMaster.

Executing the same query (all distinct Finance_Project_Number) should yield the same result in SQL and LINQ, because String / Int / ... implement `Equals()`.

```
var financeProjectNumbers = stageContext.ProjectMasters.Select(u => u.Finance_Project_Number).Where(u => !allProjectNames.Contains(u)).Distinct().ToList();
```

If you do not want to implement `Equals`, you can use this list to select all records using the following query:

```
var records = stageContect.ProjectMasters.Where(u => financeProjectNumbers.Contains(u.Finance_Project_Number)).ToList();
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and insight. The reason why I am calling the complete record in the LINQ query, is that I need to update the specific record. I did read through the post you suggested (thanks :)), but I am still too new/green to completely understand how I can implement this is my code. I also make use of 2 data sources, complicating matters a bit. May I ask that you perhaps give me some pointers on my specific code? Thank you very much!

Comment: UPDATE: I have tried the LINQ query you submitted, but as this returns only the Finance_Project_Number, my update method does not work. I need the complete record for that. Is there a way I can have this LINQ query, and still update a record that matches?

Comment: Ahhhh! I see where you are going with this. However, one small hiccup; I get an error on the .ToList(); part of this query: var records = stageContext.ProjectMasters.Where(u => financeProjectNumbers.Contains(u.Finance_Project_Number).ToList(); ERROR: 'bool' does not contain a definition for '' and no extension method '' accepting a first argument of type 'bool' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: There was a closing parentheses missing ;)

Comment: Almost there! One more small oversight. This line does return 6982 records: var financeProjectNumbers = stageContext.ProjectMasters.Select(u => u.Finance_Project_Number).ToList().Where(u => !allProjectNames.Contains(u)).Distinct().ToList(); However, this line returns everything once again, as there is no DISTINCT clause in this. I did try adding it, but it made no difference. var records = stageContext.ProjectMasters.ToList().Where(u => financeProjectNumbers.Contains(u.Finance_Project_Number)).ToList();

Comment: Oh sorry, didn't see the last comment, could you resolve it?

Comment: Thanks, Mark - I got it sorted. Thanks for all the help!