# Mapping models with Linq

Tags: c#, linq

Given a collection Book and each Book having a collection of Store. Using Linq, how can I map that to a collection of Store which has a collection of Book?

The destination classes are not the same as the origin classes.

Convert a collection of Book defined as:

```
public class Book
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Store[] Stores { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

To a collection of Store defined as:

```
public class DestinationStore
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    Book[] Books { get; set; }
}

public class DestinationBook
{
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up grouping by Store and then populating Store.Books for each Store. Thought there may have been a more elegant solution.

```
var stores = books.SelectMany(x => x.Stores).GroupBy(x => new
{
    x.Id,
    x.Name
}).Select(x => new DestinationStore
{
    Id = x.Key.Id,
    Name = x.Key.Name,
    Books = books.Where(bookFilter => bookFilter.Stores.Select(store => store.Id).Contains(x.Key.Id))
        .Select(book => new DestinationBook
        {
            Id = book.Id,
            Name = book.Name
        }).ToArray()
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public class Book
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Store[] Stores { get; set; }
}

public class Store
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static void Main()
{
    List<Book> books = new List<Book>();
    var stores = books.SelectMany(x => x.Stores) // flatMap method, returns a collection of stores
                      .Distinct() // only keep different stores
                      .Select(x => // foreach store
                          new { // create a new object
                              Store = x, // that contains the store
                              Books = books.Where(book => book.Stores.Contains(x)).ToList() // and a list of each book that is in the store
                              })
                      .ToList();
    Console.WriteLine(stores);
}
```

Instead of the anonymous data type (the `new { Store = ..., Books = ...}`), you can build up any datastructure you want, e.g. an object of your Store class that contains an array of books)

Comment: Thank you for trying to help me get over this mental block. Though there is a problem with this solution. You would need to override `Object.Equals` and `Object.GetHashCode` in order for the call to `Distinct()` to work as you'd expect. I've answered a question about this in the past http://stackoverflow.com/a/9601805/525558.

Comment: I will think about how to overcome this, i will comment again and edit my answer if something suitable comes to my mind :)

Comment: Take a look at the link I posted in the comment. It shows overriding of Equals and GetHashCode. Doing that allows you to define how the equality is determined. In addition to that you can also implement `IEquatable<T>` to improve performance as was suggested. Again much appreciate you taking the time to answer my question :)