# How can I get all nested items from a collection?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a collection of items. The one item can have another item, and another item can have another item. So on.

I do not know how many levels of nested items can have item. The level of nested items can be defined at run-time.

```
class Person
{
    Person person;
    public Person(Person _nestedPerson)
    {
        person = _nestedPerson;
    }

    public bool IsSelectedPerson { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and how items(`Person`) can be nested:

```
IList<Person> list = new List<Person>();            
for (int startIndex = 0; startIndex < 5; startIndex++)
{
   list.Add(new Person(new Person(new Person(new Person(null) { Name="Bill", 
        IsSelectedPerson=true})) { Name = "Jessy", IsSelectedPerson = false }) 
        { Name = "Bond", IsSelectedPerson =true});//3 nested persons
   list.Add(new Person(new Person(null) { Name = "Kendell", 
        IsSelectedPerson = true }) { Name="Rosy", IsSelectedPerson=true});//2 nested persons
   //The next time it can be just one person without nested item(person). I do not know how many items(persons) will be nested
   //list.Add(new Person(null) { Name="Rosy", IsSelectedPerson=true});
}
```

*My goal is to take **ALL** objects(**without duplicates**) of persons(`Person`) who `IsSelectedPerson=true`?*

I've played with `Select()`

```
var ee = list.Select(x=>x.IsSelectedFacet==true);//comparison should be done here
```

but it is not what I want, it just takes `bool` values.

**Update:**

**My expected result should be have one object of `Person` with unique name. No matter how many there are objects with the same name. I would like to take just one object. Sorry for misleading. It should be look like this:**

[image]

Comment: Do you have any restriction on a nesting depth?

Comment: `FacetStorage.Where(p => p.IsSelectedFacet);`

Comment: @Valentin no, there is no restriction on a nesting depth

Comment: @Jodrell yeah, I've tried  
`coll.Where(p => p.IsSelectedPerson);`, but this query just takes upper objests, not nested objects.

Comment: @StepUp, first you need to "flatten" the nested people. There are several ways to do this, I prefer a linq way that doesn't involve allocating an arbritraily long list.

Comment: If you have already solved the recursive list, you can use groupBy Name with linq, and then select first, like in this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19406242/select-distinct-using-linq

Comment: @downvoter what is the reason to downvote? it is really interesting:). Could you provide explanation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make a helper method to unwrap all nested objects

```
    IEnumerable<Person> UnwrapPerson(Person p)
    {
        List<Person> list = new List<Person>();
        list.Add(p);
        if (p.person != null)
            list.AddRange(UnwrapPerson(p.person));

        return list;
    }
```

Or if `Person` class has only one nested object (`Person person;`) you can use a `yield` construction instead of the recursion

```
    static IEnumerable<Person> UnwrapPerson(Person p)
    {
        yield return p;
        while (p.person != null)
        {
            p = p.person;
            yield return p;
        }
    }
```

In order to remove all duplicate persons, for example with the same name, you should implement `IEqualityComparer<Person>` and then use `Distinct` method.

```
class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<Person>
{
    public bool Equals(Person x, Person y)
    {
        return string.Equals(x.Name, y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Person obj)
    {
        string name = obj.Name;
        int hash = 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < name.Length; i++)
        {
            hash = hash * 31 + name[i];
        }

        return hash;
    }
}
```

So final query should be similar to:

```
 list.SelectMany(p => UnwrapPerson(p))
     .Where(x => x.IsSelectedPerson == true)
     .Distinct(new Comparer())
```

Comment: @StepUp I've added duplicates removing.

Comment: I've tried your solution, however there are duplicates.

Comment: @StepUp What do you mean by duplicates? With the same name? or object with nested object? Are you running the last query?

Comment: with the same `Name`. yeah, I've tried your last query.

Comment: @StepUp Im running this code on my machine, and it works fine. Can you share what are you running?

Comment: ooops, sorry, Valentin, your solution is correct! Many thanks to you! I upvoted answer. But I really would like to minimize the necessary code to write. So I am trying to use solution with `yield` keyword.

Comment: @StepUp you still need to use  `IEqualityComparer` in order to remove duplicates, even with the `yield` solution. Thanks.

Comment: that's a c&p of my answer -1

Answer (score 3):

Here is another approach to yield your list of items:

```
IEnumerable<Person> GetIsSelectedPerson(Person p)
{
    Person temp = p;
    while (temp != null)
    {
        if (temp.IsSelectedPerson)
        {
            yield return temp;
        }
        temp = temp.person;
    }           
}
```

**Usage:**

```
IEnumerable<Person> Result = GetIsSelectedPerson(rootPerson)
```

Comment: I cannot figure out, how can I iterate through nested persons? could you provide complete code?

Comment: ok, but how can I take nested person? sorry for my dummy questions:). please, provide full code

Comment: the `Person temp` is going through your nested `Persons` and returns the item in case `IsSelectedPerson` - this is the full code

Comment: @StepUp As I consider, you should use `SelectMany` method for the `list`. `list.SelectMany(x=> GetIsSelectedPerson(x))`

Comment: a lot of duplicate objects. I would like just single objects. Is it possible without duplicates? thanks in advance

Comment: should be `GetIsSelectedPerson(rootPerson).Distinct()` with an overridden `==` operator

Comment: Please, could you show you thoughts expressed in code?:) I am really not cool programmer:). How can I connect `Distinct()` and overridden `==` operator? Thanks in advance

Comment: here is the code for a custom distinct http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601674/creating-a-distinct-list-of-custom-type-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 2):

I would use some kind of visiting pattern with recursion to visit all the nested `Persons`:

```
class Person
{
   public static List<Person> selectedPersons;
   Person person;
   public Person(Person _nestedPerson)
   {
       if(selectedPersons == null)
         selectedPersons = new List<Person>();
       person = _nestedPerson;
   }

   public bool IsSelectedPerson { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }

   public void Visit()
   {
       if(this.IsSelectedPerson)
         selectedPersons.Add(this);
       if(this.person != null)
         this.person.Visit();
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however,  I cannot change my model class.

Comment: @StepUp Maybe an extension method could do it? And pass the list as a parameter to it

Answer (score 1):

Do this to flatten the people,

```
Func<Person, IEnumerable<Person>> flattener = null;
flattener = p => new[] { p }
    .Concat(
        p.person == null 
            ? Enumerable.Empty<Person>()
            : (new [] { p.Person }).SelectMany(child => flattener(child)));
```

So you can do this,

```
flattener(person).Where(p => p.IsSelectedPerson);
```

---

Following you comments, what you possibly want is,

```
flattener(person)
   .Where(p => p.IsSelectedPerson)
   .Select(p => p.Name)
   .Distinct();
```

Comment: I am trying your solution, however `p` does not have `Person` field. I mean this: `.Concat(p.Person`. `p` just has `IsSelectedPerson` and `Name`.

Comment: @StepUp, try with a lower case `p`, is the Person nested in the Person publically accesible?

Comment: thanks, I've edited to `public`. However, there are many duplicates. How can I remove it?

Comment: `Distinct` will help but you'll need to `Equals` and `GetHashCode` if you want different instances to be the same

Comment: sorry for misleading, I mean that I would like to get just objects with Distinct `Name` property.

Comment: `Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<string>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<linqGetAllBoolsNestedItemsFromColl.Person>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)`

Comment: @SetUp are all `Person` with the same name the same or, if not, which `Person` do you want?

Comment: yeah, all `Person` with the same name is the same. So I just want to delete all persons with the same name, and to get a result with the unique `Name` of `Person`. Please, see updated section of my question. sorry for misleading.

Comment: @StepUp them implement `Equals` and `GetHashCode` like in Valentin's answer and just do 'flattener(person).Where(p => p.IsSelectedPerson).Distinct();`

Answer (score 1):

Since you don't know the level of persons in the chain, the best is to use recursion. Two simple solutions (suppose you add the methods on Person class)

1. Create a method that receives a list, so you can fill it in the recursive call:
       List completeList = new List();
       list[0].GetCompleteList(completeList);
       list[1].GetCompleteList(completeList);

   ```
   public void GetCompleteList(List<Person> personsList)
   {
       personsList.Add(this);
       if (person != null)
       {
           person.GetCompleteList(personsList);
       }
   }
   ```
2. The same, without parameter

   ```
   List<Person> completeList = new List<Person>();
   completeList.AddRange(list[0].GetCompleteList());
   completeList.AddRange(list[1].GetCompleteList());

   // Another way: with linq
   var myPersons  list.SelectMany(m => m.GetCompleteList());

   public List<Person> GetCompleteList()
    {
        List<Person> returnList = new List<Person>();
        returnList.Add(this);
        if (person != null)
        {
            returnList.AddRange(person.GetCompleteList());
        }
        return returnList;
    }
   ```