# Distinct values from list of custom class

Tags: c#

I have class to `MerkmalSet` which removes duplicates from `Merkmalls` list in method `RemoveAllInstancesOfDuplicates`. However target it to make a distinct instead, how should i change my method to do so.

```
public class MerkmalRow
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Wert { get; set; }

    public MerkmalRow(string name, string wert)
    {
        Name = name;
        Wert = wert;
    }
}

public class MerkmalSet
{
    public List<MerkmalRow> Merkmalls;

    public void AddNewRow(MerkmalRow newRow)
    {
        if (Merkmalls == null)
            Merkmalls = new List<MerkmalRow>();
        Merkmalls.Add(newRow);
    }

    public void RemoveAllInstancesOfDuplicates()
    {
        var withoutAllInstancesOfDuplicates = new List<MerkmalRow>();

        foreach (MerkmalRow entry in Merkmalls)
        {
            if (Merkmalls.Count(row =>
                    string.Equals(row.Name, entry.Name) &&
                    string.Equals(row.Wert, entry.Wert)) == 1)
            {
                withoutAllInstancesOfDuplicates.Add(entry);
            }
        }
        Merkmalls = null;
        Merkmalls = withoutAllInstancesOfDuplicates;
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a distinct list of custom type in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9601674/creating-a-distinct-list-of-custom-type-in-c-sharp)

Comment: Hey Dino, would you explain with a little more detail what do you mean by distinct? You want to maintain a single instance of a duplicated value even if they are deleted?

Answer (score 1):

You first need to create an `IEqualityComparer<MerkmalRow>` that compares `MerkmalRow` objects.

```
public class MerkmalRowComparer : IEqualityComparer<MerkmalRow>
{
    bool IEqualityComparer<MerkmalRow>.Equals(MerkmalRow x, MerkmalRow y)
    {
        // reference equality
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;

        // check for null
        if (ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
            return false;

        // check if each property is the same value
        return x.Name == y.Name && x.Wert == y.Wert;
    }

    int IEqualityComparer<MerkmalRow>.GetHashCode(MerkmalRow obj)
    {
        unchecked
        {
            var hashCode = obj.Name != null ? obj.Name.GetHashCode() : 0;
            hashCode = (hashCode * 397) ^ (obj.Wert != null ? obj.Wert.GetHashCode() : 0);
            return hashCode;
        }
    }
}
```

Then use LINQ's `Distinct` method, passing it the comparer object so that it knows how to compare each object in the list:

```
public void RemoveAllInstancesOfDuplicates()
{
    Merkmalls = Merkmalls.Distinct(new MerkmalRowComparer()).ToList();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Mayhem suggests you can use a hashset. To do that you need to declare `MerkmalRow` as a `Struct` (or implement equality)

```
using Xunit;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System;

public struct MerkmalRow
{
    public string Name { get; }
    public string Wert { get; }

    public MerkmalRow(string name, string wert)
    {
        Name = name;
        Wert = wert;
    }
}

public class MerkmalSet
{
    public HashSet<MerkmalRow> Merkmalls = new HashSet<MerkmalRow>();

    public void AddNewRow(MerkmalRow newRow) => Merkmalls.Add(newRow);
}

public class Tests 
{
    [Fact]
    public void DuplicatesAreNotAdded() 
    {
        var merkmalSet = new MerkmalSet();
        merkmalSet.AddNewRow(new MerkmalRow("1", "2"));
        merkmalSet.AddNewRow(new MerkmalRow("1", "2"));
        merkmalSet.AddNewRow(new MerkmalRow("1", "2"));
        merkmalSet.AddNewRow(new MerkmalRow("1", "3"));

        Assert.Equal(2, merkmalSet.Merkmalls.Count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually want to keep a single instance of the items in the list (without repetition), you can have the following method

```
 public void RemoveDuplicates()
 {
      set = new HashSet<MerkmalRow>(Merkmalls);
      Merkmalls = set.ToList();
 }
```

As ingvar mentions, the link also suggests that you can use LINQ to update your list like this `Merkmalls = Merkmalls.Distinct().ToList();`

Comment: to me it keeps items

Comment: yes, because the individual MerkmakRow object instances aren't equal...

Comment: can you update RemoveDuplicates to really make distincts?

Comment: I've added an answer but if you change MerkmalRow to struct and use Mayhem's answer it should work. Struct equality is based on their properties.

Comment: If you store the Merkmalls in a hashset you don't even need the remove duplicates method. It simply never adds them

Comment: **Class** objects are not evaluated on the basis of field-by-field equality, **anonymous types** are. So, `HashSet` cannot evaluate duplicates here.

Comment: My mistake, I should have updated the LINQ with the correct form

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of all the complications:

```
Merkmalls = Merkmalls
                .GroupBy(x => new { Name = x.Name, Wert= x.Wert})
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();
```

and also for removing all duplicates:

```
Merkmalls = Merkmalls
                .GroupBy(x => new { Name = x.Name, Wert= x.Wert})
                .Where(g => g.Count() == 1)
                .Select(g => g.First())
                .ToList();
```

I always prefer to use the power of LinQ instead of creating my own methods.